# How to delete all items in the bucket?

Tags: couchbase

I was wondering how can i delete all the items in the Couchbase bucket.
I'm using java client.

I've tried to run `client.flush()` method. Flush is enabled on bucket.
But it throws exception :

```
Exception in thread "Temporary Flusher" java.lang.RuntimeException: Http Error: 401 Reason: Unauthorized Details: No reason given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in CouchBase Server 2.0. Use the `ClusterManager class` with the Administrator credentials

[found here](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/flush-gui-works-not-spy-memcached)

Comment: Note that this shoud be fixed in the released 2.0.1 of Couchbase Server that is available for download http://www.couchbase.com/download