# Is flush method missing in couchbase python client?

Tags: python, couchbase, couchdb-python

I did not find the flush button for bucket in couchbase admin UI at port 8091 .May be because of this http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-5351 .

Then I saw this [How to delete all items in the bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966769/how-to-delete-all-items-in-the-bucket) so I wanted to do flush in python client .

```
import sys
from couchbase import Couchbase
from couchbase.exceptions import CouchbaseError
try:
    client = Couchbase.connect(bucket='production',host='localhost',port=8091)
except CouchbaseError as e:
    print " Sorry , we could not create connection to bucket specified , due to " , e
else :
    print "Successfully made the connection to bucket "
```

Here client i did not find a method to flush . I tried intellisense in IDE .

Please guide me to flush the bucket via python client .

Comment: In the UI there should be an option to enable flushing a bucket. Can you make sure that this radio box is checked.

Comment: The 'Flush' button is in the *edit* dialog of a button; but you need to enable the flush option (also in the *edit* dialog) before it appears.

Comment: Ya I am able to see the flush button . Thanks . But why there is no way to flush from couchbase python client.

Comment: So looking at the .NET Couchbase SDK, they have a flushbucket() - and the Python SDK doesn't? That can't be right...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the couchbase python SDK does not currently provide a flush() method.
But since the flush method is provided through the couchbase REST API you may use it to flush your bucket.

Reference: Couchbase REST API, Buckets API - http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-bucket-intro.html

The python SDK provides an **Admin** object which you can use to perform your administrator tasks using REST using its **http_request** method.
source code: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/admin.py

description of the Admin class (from source):

> An administrative connection to a Couchbase cluster.
>
> ```
> With this object, you can do things which affect the cluster, such as
> modifying buckets, allocating nodes, or retrieving information about
> the cluster.
>
> This object should **not** be used to perform Key/Value operations. The
> :class:`couchbase.bucket.Bucket` is used for that.
> ```

Admin.http_request method description (from source):

> ```
>     Perform an administrative HTTP request. This request is sent out to
>     the administrative API interface (i.e. the "Management/REST API")
>     of the cluster.
>
>     See <LINK?> for a list of available comments.
>
>     Note that this is a fairly low level function. This class will with
>     time contain more and more wrapper methods for common tasks such
>     as bucket creation or node allocation, and this method should
>     mostly be used if a wrapper is not available.
> ```

---

Example:

First make sure that the Flush option is enabled for your bucket.

I created a test bucket named "default" for the example and created 2 documents within the bucket.

```
import sys
from couchbase import Couchbase
from couchbase.exceptions import CouchbaseError

#import Admin module
from couchbase.admin import Admin


#make an administrative connection using Admin object
try:
    admin = Admin(username='Administrator',password='password',host='localhost',port=8091)
except CouchbaseError as e:
    print " Sorry , we could not create admin connection , due to " , e
else :
    print "Successfully made an admin connection "


#retrieve bucket information for bucket named "default" 
#   "default" is just the name of the bucket I set up for trying this out
try:
    htres = admin.http_request("/pools/default/buckets/default")
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: ", e
    sys.exit()


#print the current number of items in the "default" bucket
#   "default" is just the name of the bucket I set up for trying this out
print "# of items before flush: ", htres.value['basicStats']['itemCount']


#flush bucket
try:
    #the bucket information request returned the path to the REST flush method for this bucket
    #   the flush method requires a POST request
    htres = admin.http_request(htres.value['controllers']['flush'],"POST")
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: ", e
    sys.exit()


#re-retrieve bucket information for bucket named "default" 
try:
    htres = admin.http_request("/pools/default/buckets/default")
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: ", e
    sys.exit()


#print the number of items in the "default" bucket (after flush)
print "# of items after flush: ", htres.value['basicStats']['itemCount']
```

result:

> ```
> Successfully made an admin connection 
> # of items before flush:  2
> # of items after flush:  0
> ```

Comment: That might work, but what about code that doesn't have access to the Administator password? (Which is why I was looking for a way to do it using the Python SDK in the first place).

Comment: seems they have an open issue...since last year. https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PYCBC-214

Comment: @JohnC unfortunately I stopped looking once i came to the solution above. After reading your comment, I did try quickly with username=None and password=None and was still able to connect and flush the bucket on my default setup (Though I have not taken the time to figure out why it allowed me to do that... It may be something you can look into further though).